# How to convert PNG with alpha to JPEG conserving colors using JAVA

Tags: java, colors, png, jpeg, alpha

I'm having some trouble in converting a PNG with Alpha to JPEG from Wiki.

This is the image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Radio_SRF_3.svg/500px-Radio_SRF_3.svg.png

Original:
[image]

The converted JPEG file has wrong colors. It's more grey than darker now.
[image: image result]

This is how I do the conversion:

Remove alpha:

```
public static BufferedImage imageFillAlphaWithColor(BufferedImage image, Color fillColor) {
    if (image.getColorModel().getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE) return image;

    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, fillColor, null);
    g.dispose();

    return newImage;
}
```

Jpeg compression:

```
public static byte[] compressedJpegImage(BufferedImage image, float quality) {
        byte jpegImage[] = null;
        try {
            // Find a jpeg writer
            ImageWriter writer = null;
            Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
            }

            // Prepare output
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            // Set the compression quality
            ImageWriteParam iwparam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            iwparam.setProgressiveMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT);
            iwparam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            iwparam.setCompressionQuality(quality);

            // Write the image
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), iwparam);

            // Cleanup
            ios.flush();
            writer.dispose();
            ios.close();

            jpegImage = os.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jpegImage;
    }
```

And store it to JPEG via ImageIO.

Any idea how to preserve the color space to keep the colors like they are in the original?

**UPDATE**

Issue was caused by ImageMagick when resized. Seems like ImageMagick did change the color space to TYPE_CUSTOM and Java is not able to handle that.

Current solution:

Remove alpha just before I start resizing the image via ImageMagick.

Still haven't found a solution to convert the color space from "CUSTOM" back to "ARGB".
So this is just a "workaround" for this issue.

Comment: Try storing the image after alpha removal as `PNG` (or better yet, display it directly in Java without storing), to see if the problem is in the removal of alpha, *or* in the JPEG store part.

Comment: @haraldK I just stored the image as PNG just after imageFillAlphaWithColor(..) and the result is the same as storing to JPEG. Looks like the there is something missing inside imageFillAlphaWithColor(..) or I'm missing some color information that are available inside the original image.

Comment: Perhaps the original image has gray color space (`ColorSpace.CS_GRAY`)? Could be that some implicit color conversion is going on, and doing the wrong thing... If so, try using `ColorConvertOp` to convert to RGB before painting, and see it if helps (sorry, I'm on a limited time budget.. :-P) .

Comment: @haraldK this could be the issue. I just tested with an colorful image and it worked fine. The image above got TYPE_CUSTOM as color type. Will try to convert to RGB first.

Comment: BufferedImage is tricky with gray images, because of color spaces  confusions: eg. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5051418

Comment: I can't manage it to convert the above image from its (custom?) color space to my desired (A)RGB color space. Maybe I should switch to ImageMagick, although I though I could manage this "small" task with Java only.

Comment: @Arny: Don't panic! :-) It seems @leonbloy found a bug that describes precisely the problem you ran into. However, I think it should be possible to do a `ColorConvertOp` that does the conversion.

Comment: PS: What Java version/platform do you use? I just tried your code, and could not reproduce... Looks as it should here.

Comment: @haraldK Java 1.7, OSX. What did you use?

Comment: @Arny: Sorry, should have mentioned. Oracle jdk1.7.0_45 on Windows. I can try OS X tonight, if I find the time.

Comment: @haraldK strange. You did take the original image from wikipedia and used the same fill method as listed above? Can't imagine why would there be a difference between platforms.

Comment: @haraldK I just found my issue, I think. Oddly this seems to be related to the image I used above only. I'm using ImageMagick to downsize the images as I get them from the web. When resizing the image above, it becomes TYPE_CUSTOM. Before resizing it is TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR. So Java seems like to not be able to handle it from then on.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually removing the alpha values. Java divides the color values by the alpha when you do what you did in the `imageFillAlphaWithColor` method.

I recommend using the [`AlphaComposite` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) to actually remove the alpha.

Here's the Oracle tutorial on how to Composite Graphics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

Without being able to test easily, I *think* what you need to do is this:

```
Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, fillColor, null);
```

If that doesn't work, read this related question: [Change the alpha value of a BufferedImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660580/change-the-alpha-value-of-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: your solution didn't work, but I'll take a closer look at the provided links. Thanks

Comment: @Arny I was afraid of that, I hate offering solutions that I can't test. That last link has three solutions though, hopefully you can get one of them to work.

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, fillColor, null)` should fill any transparent parts with `fillColor`, so I think the OPs code is good. The default composite is `AlphaComposite.SrcOver`.

Comment: Tested `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null)` with `AlphaComposite.SrcOver` and stored the result using `ImageIO.write(...,"jpeg",...) - I got a jpeg that looks identical to the source image.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Color fillColor = Color.BLUE; // just to verify
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\temp\\tGjhw.png"));
        BufferedImage bi2 = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(),
              BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        bi2.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, fillColor, null);
        // you can do a more complex saving to tune the compression  parameters
        ImageIO.write(bi2,"JPG",new File("c:\\temp\\tGjhw2.jpg"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The too-light result appears to be due to a conversion from linear colorspace (gamma=1) to sRGB (gamma=1/2.2).  The original doesn't contain any gamma information, so ImageMagick is free to choose its own default.  Recent versions of ImageMagick handle grayscale images differently, some assuming linear and others assuming sRGB.  From the commandline you'd use the "-gamma 1" option to get the darker result with all versions.  You need to do the equivalent in Java.