# BufferedImage set alpha from other BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, alpha, alphablending

I got 3 BufferedImages: A, C and D. All are images with colors and an alpha channel. C has to alpha-over D, but with the transparency layer of A. The idea is to:

- Set the alpha channel of C to that of A
- Alpha over them

I do the alpha mixing with `new BufferedImage().createGraphics().drawImage(D).drawImage(C);`. But how do I set the alpha of C?

I'm open to any suggestions using BufferedImage, but I'd prefer those that don't iterate over all pixels and do the calculations manually to increase performance (in the hope it does).

Comment: Take a look to similar posts, just like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660580/change-the-alpha-value-of-a-bufferedimage).

Answer (score 0):

For an image with uniform alpha you can do the following:

```
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
  bim=ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
}
catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error in bim "+ex); }
int wc=bim.getWidth(), hc=bim.getHeight();
  BufferedImage b=new BufferedImage(wc, hc, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  b.getGraphics().drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);
  BufferedImage b2=new BufferedImage(wc, hc, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  RescaleOp no=new RescaleOp(new float[]{1f, 1, 1, 1f}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, -50}, null);
  b2=no.filter(b, null);

  BufferedImage b3=new BufferedImage(wc, hc, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  b3.getGraphics().drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);
  float offset=(b2.getRGB(0, 0)&0xff000000)>>24, a=(b3.getRGB(0, 0)&0xff000000)>>24;
  no=new RescaleOp(new float[]{1, 1, 1, 1}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, -a+offset}, null);
  b3=no.filter(b3, null);
```

Now b3 has the alpha of b2.

For an image with non-uniform alpha you have to work pixel per pixel.

Comment: What do you mean with "uniform alpha"? If it's "alpha is same everywhere", that's not the case.

Comment: yea then pixel by pixel I have no other choice